# Reading a line with scientific numbers (like 0.4E-03)

Tags: python

I would like to process the following line (output of a Fortran program) from a file, with Python:

```
74      0.4131493371345440E-03  -0.4592776407685850E-03  -0.1725046324754540
```

and obtain an array such as:

```
[74,0.4131493371345440e-3,-0.4592776407685850E-03,-0.1725046324754540]
```

My previous attempts do not work. In particular, if I do the following :

```
with open(filename,"r") as myfile:
    line=np.array(re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.*\d+",myfile.readline())).astype(float)
```

I have the following error :

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'E-03'
```

Comment: You need to fix the regexp so that it includes the exponent.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42093745/1491895 for example.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use a regular expression? If the file just contains numbers separated by whitespace, just use `split()`.

Comment: @Barmar
Indeed, you were right. The following expression solved my problem:
`line=np.array(myfile.readline().split()).astype(float)`
Thank you very much

Comment: You might want to use `decimal` for better precision

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Get list of strings (`str.split(' ')`)
- Get rid of "\n" (`del arr[-1]`)
- Turn list of strings into numbers ([Converting a string (with scientific notation) to an int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338507/converting-a-string-with-scientific-notation-to-an-int-in-python))

Code:

```
import decimal # you may also leave this out and use `float` instead of `decimal.Decimal()`

arr = "74 0.4131493371345440E-03 -0.4592776407685850E-03 -0.1725046324754540 \n"
arr = arr.split(' ')
del arr[-1]
arr = [decimal.Decimal(x) for x in arr]
# do your np stuff
```

Result:

```
>>> print(arr)
[Decimal('74'), Decimal('0.0004131493371345440'), Decimal('-0.0004592776407685850'), Decimal('-0.1725046324754540')]
```

PS:

- I don't know if you wrote the file that gives the output in the first place, but if you did, you could just think about outputting an array of `float()` / `decimal.Decimal()` from that file instead.

Answer (score 0):

@ant.kr Here is a possible solution:

```
# Initial data
a = "74 0.4131493371345440E-03 -0.4592776407685850E-03 -0.1725046324754540 \n"

# Given the structure of the initial data, we can proceed as follow:
# - split the initial at each white space; this will produce  **list** with the last
#   the element being **\n**
# - we can now convert each list element into a floating point data, store them in a
#   numpy array.
line = np.array([float(i) for i in a.split(" ")[:-1]])
```