# sum filesize with different unit

Tags: python, python-3.x

in my cloud, my persistent volumes size is like

```
sizes=["10Gi", "100Gi","10Gi" "1Ti","2Ti"]
```

I want sum them all with "Ti" as unit finally, I'm not sure how to get it done, or is there a library to do this ?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240303/separate-number-from-unit-in-a-string-in-python?

Comment: You will get better answers if you show what exactly you expect to get as a result, and what has been the specific difficulty you were facing, as opposed to what you already know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may

- filter for those that ends with `Ti`
- convert to `int` the numeric part
- `sum` all of that

That can be one easily with the `sum` method and a generator

```
sizes = ["10Gi", "100Gi", "10Gi", "1Ti", "2Ti"]
total_ti = sum(int(x.rstrip("Ti")) for x in sizes if x.endswith("Ti"))
print(total_ti)  # 3
```

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a library to do this

Comment: @user1334609 I'm quite sure there is not, that's a it specific. "sum string that has given suffix" that's quite specific