# Provide name of value with largest speed

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a python script which reads in a csv file and then prints out the column value with the largest speed.

The CSV is formatted as such:

```
name, cartype, speed
vauxall, car, 99.0mph
bugati, bike, 120.0mph
mercedes, car, 134.0mph
```

I would expect my script to print out:

```
mercedes
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('cars.csv')

row_with_max_speed = df.loc[df["speed"].idxmax()]

print(f"{row_with_max_speed.name}")
```

I think I am having an issue with speed due to the values having "mph" within them

Comment: then remove the mph

Comment: i need to have mph in the data

Comment: Could the units be anything other than mph? `C172, plane, 115kias`?

Comment: it's all in mph

Comment: Then consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240303/separate-number-from-unit-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: @kojiro Character by character? That's super inefficient. Just strip "mph".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the numeric part of speed and convert it to float before calculating `idxmax`:

```
df.loc[df["speed"].str[:-3].astype(float).idxmax(), "name"]
```

Output:

```
mercedes
```

UPD: changed `apply` to `astype` to support None values in `speed` column

Comment: the str[:-3], if the column was to have say just 100.0m, would we use str[:-1]?

Comment: Correct! Although this will work only if all values have the same suffix. Mixed meters and mph will break this approach.

Comment: would this solution be able to skip over column values that are null in the csv?

Comment: Good question! No, but I've update the answer so that it works if `speed` has None values in it! The only change is `apply -> astype`

Answer (score 2):

The main issue you're running in to is the formatting of your CSV file.
The spaces infront of 'speed' and 'cartype' mean that the keys are actually
[' speed'] with a space infront. Ideally though, you should remove the spaces from your csv file.

Once you've fixed that, you can do something like

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("cars.csv")

df["speed"] = df["speed"].str.replace("mph", "").astype(float)
fastest_car = df.loc[df["speed"].idxmax()]
print(fastest_car)
```

Which will fix the problem with your mph issue by removing the string and casting it to a float, then finding the fastest one.

Comment: You can use the `skipinitialspace=True` option to ignore those spaces.